# Operator overloading for nested struct only working as member or friend function

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, friend

This C++ code compiles and runs perfectly, as I expect:

```c++
template <typename T>  struct S { T *p; };

template <typename T>
bool operator == (S<T> &a, S<T> &b) { return a.p == b.p; }

int main () { int i;  S<int> a = {&i}, b = {&i};  return a == b; }
```

However, if I try to do the same with the inner struct of an outer struct...

```c++
template <typename T>  struct O {  struct I {T *p;};  };

template <typename T>
bool operator == (O<T>::I &a, O<T>::I &b) { return a.p == b.p; }

int main () { int i;  O<int>::I a = {&i}, b = {&i};  return a == b; }
```

... then it doesn't compile anymore (gcc version 8.3.0, Debian GNU/Linux 10):

```c++
1.cpp:4:25: error: declaration of ‘operator==’ as non-function
 bool operator == (O<T>::I &a, O<T>::I &b) { return a.p == b.p; }
                         ^
[...]
```

**Why is it so?** I also do not understand the above error message.

Note that I'm aware that I can make it work by [defining the operator as a member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison) of the inner struct:

```c++
template <typename T>
struct O2 {
           struct I2 {
                      T *p;

                      bool operator == (I2 &b) { return p == b.p; }
                     };
          };

int main () { int i;  O2<int>::I2 a = {&i}, b = {&i};  return a == b; }
```

However, if somehow possible, I'd rather use the non-member function version, because I find it more symmetric and therefore clearer.

Also, partly by trial and error, I found that the following symmetric version works...

```c++
template <typename T>
struct O3 {
           struct I3 { T *p; };

           friend bool operator == (I3 &a, I3 &b) { return a.p == b.p; }
          };

int main () { int i;  O3<int>::I3 a = {&i}, b = {&i};  return a == b; }
```

... but I do not really understand what is happening above. First, given that a [friend declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) "grants a function or another class access to private and protected members of the class where the friend declaration appears", I do not understand how it helps in the code above, given that we're always dealing with structs and therefore with public members.

Second, if I remove the `friend` specifier, then it doesn't compile anymore. Also, the `[...] operator== [...] must have exactly one argument` error message makes me think that in this case the compiler expects me to define a member function `operator==` whose left operand is `O3`, not `I3`. Apparently, however, the `friend` specifier changes this situation; **why is it so?**

Comment: Relevant, if not a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the compiler gets confused by missing `typename`. The error message really is confusing and can be silenced via:

```
template <typename T>
bool operator == (typename O<T>::I &a, typename O<T>::I &b) { 
    return a.p == b.p; 
}
```

Now the actual problem gets more apparent:

```
int main () { 
    int i;  
    O<int>::I a = {&i}, b = {&i};  
    return a == b; 
}
```

results in the error:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:15:14: error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'O<int>::I' and 'O<int>::I')
   15 |     return a == b;
      |            ~ ^~ ~
      |            |    |
      |            |    I<[...]>
      |            I<[...]>
<source>:8:6: note: candidate: 'template<class T> bool operator==(typename O<T>::I&, typename O<T>::I&)'
    8 | bool operator == (typename O<T>::I &a, typename O<T>::I &b) {
      |      ^~~~~~~~
<source>:8:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:15:17: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'
   15 |     return a == b;
      |                 ^
```

It is not possible to deduce `T` from `a == b`, (@dfribs words)

> because `T` is in a non-deduced context in both of the function
> parameters of the operator function template; `T` cannot be deduced
> from `O<T>::I&`, meaning `T` cannot be deduced from any of the
> arguments to the call (and function template argument deduction
> subsequently fails).

Sloppy speaking, because `O<S>::I` could be the same as `O<T>::I`, even if `S != T`.

When the operator is declared as member then there is only one candidate to compare a `O<T>::I` with another (because the operator itself is not a template, ie no deduction needed).

---

If you want to implement the operator as non member I would suggest to not define `I` inside `O`:

```
template <typename T> 
struct I_impl {
    T *p;
}; 

template <typename T>
bool operator == (I_impl<T> &a,I_impl<T> &b) {
     return a.p == b.p; 
}

template <typename T>  
struct O {  
    using I = I_impl<T>;  
};

int main () { 
    int i;  
    O<int>::I a = {&i}, b = {&i};  
    return a == b; 
}
```

---

Your confusion about `friend` is somewhat unrelated to operator overloading. Consider:

```
#include <iostream>

void bar();

struct foo {
    friend void bar(){ std::cout << "1";}
    void bar(){ std::cout << "2";}
};

int main () { 
    bar();
    foo{}.bar();
}
```

Output:

```
12
```

We have two definitions for a `bar` in `foo`. `friend void bar(){ std::cout << "1";}` declares the free function `::bar` (already declared in global scope) as a friend of `foo` and defines it. `void bar(){ std::cout << "2";}` declares (and defines) a member of `foo` called `bar`: `foo::bar`.

Back to `operator==`, consider that `a == b` is a shorther way of writing either

```
a.operator==(b);  // member ==
```

or

```
operator==(a,b);  // non member ==
```

Member methods get the `this` pointer as implicit parameter passed, free functions not. Thats why `operator==` must take exactly one parameter as member and exactly two as free function and this is wrong:

```
struct wrong {
    bool operator==( wrong a, wrong b);
};
```

while this is correct:

```
struct correct {
    bool operator==(wrong a);
};
struct correct_friend {
    friend operator==(wrong a,wrong b);
};
```

Comment: ... non-sloppy speaking because `T` is in a non-deduced context in both of the function parameters of the operator function template; `T` cannot be deduced from `O<T>::I&`, meaning `T` cannot be deduced from any of the arguments to the call (and function template argument deduction subsequently fails).

Answer (score 2):

Compiling C++ does not require compilers to solve the halting problem.

```
template <typename T>  struct O {  struct I {T *p;};  };

template <typename T>
bool operator == (typename O<T>::I &a, typename O<T>::I &b) { return a.p == b.p; }
```

going from `O<int>::I` to `int` requires, in the general case, that the compiler solve the halting problem.  To demonstrate why:

```
template <typename T>  struct O {  struct I {T *p;};  };
template <>  struct O<double> {  using I=O<int>::I;  };
template <>  struct O<char> {  using I=std::string;  };

template <typename T>
bool operator == (typename O<T>::I &a, typename O<T>::I &b) { return a.p == b.p; }
```

now, `O<int>::I` can be named `O<double>::I`.  You can actually make the map from `O<T>::I` to `T` require inverting an arbitrary turing-complete function, as template specialization is turing-complete.

Rather than carving out a region of invertable dependent type maps, C++ simply says "do not invert dependent types" when doing template pattern matching of arguments.

So

```
template <typename T>
bool operator == (typename O<T>::I &a, typename O<T>::I &b) { return a.p == b.p; }
```

will **never** deduce `T`.

---

Now you can make this work, but it requires that you define the inverse mapping without relying on template type deduction.

By far the easiest is to make `I` be defined outside `O`.  Failing that, you need to define a way to find `O<T>` given `O<T>::I`, like:

```
template <typename T>  struct O {
  struct I {using Outer=O<T>;T *p;};
};
template<class Inner>
using Outer=typename Inner::Outer;
template<class X>
struct Type0;
template<template<class...>class Z, class T0, class...Ts>
struct Type0<Z<T0,Ts...>>{ using type=T0; };
template<class X>
using Type0_t=typename Type0<X>::type;
```

we can then

```
template <class I> requires (std::is_same_v<I, typename O<Type0_t<Outer<Inner>>>::I>)
bool operator == (Inner const &a, Inner const &b) { return a.p == b.p; }
```

and your code works.